# Getting error when searching for object by ID using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to search for an object by id but I'm getting the following error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id"

Here is my code:

```
var orgID = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId( org_id.organisation_id  ); //org_id.organisation_id is a string value for the object I'm trying to find below

Organisation.findById({
                orgID
            }, function (err, org) {

                if (!err) {
                    console.log("Org data: "+org);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("The following error occurred: "+err);
                }


            });
```

console.log(org_id.organisation_id);

gives me: 5661639afef20a5cc806d476

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your findById query looks wrong. The correct format is:

```
Organisation.findById(orgID, function(err,org)
```

No need to pass the argument as json. The first parameter requires the ObjectId but you were passing an Object to the function.